# Splash screen during async

Tags: android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I have an android app which does a lot of background processing on launch so for this I've set a content view with an indeterminate progress bar and then during async onprogressupdate I've set the text of the action being carried out. I would like to instead display my own splash screen with again a textview underneath where I can display the current action. I've researched into using surfaceviews and a thread - I'm not sure however if this is the best way to do this. I plan on displaying a sequence of pngs similar to a boot animation which loops until the async finishes.

So my question is: is a surface view class that implements the runnable the best way to accomplish this or is there a better way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a surface view here? I think it's enough to have a simple ImageView. You can change the current png image using Handler.postDelayed() or just create an AnimationDrawable

Comment: @vmironov would this not run on the UI thread? If so how do I allow the async to continue? I'm thinking a loop in onprogressupdate, not that doesn't sound safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went for AnimationDrawable in the end which was easy to use and worked amazingly. Credit to vmironov for the idea, unfortunately I can't accept a comment as an answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm note quite sure about my answer but I guess surfaceview is a more reliable option for this task. If you use several PNGs instead then you need to cache them for memory purposes and this might cause a little problem for your invalidate method in your animation loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a transparent activity as your splash screen which would allow you to do pretty much anything you want whilst it was displayed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would have my main activity start the splash activity. Would this not cause onpause to be called?

Comment: Yes it would. Sorry, I thought you were showing the splash screen before your main activity not afterwards.

Comment: I see. Nope I'd like to run it as a replacement of a indeterminate progress bar